# PHP current time greater than time in future error

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

I'm trying to calculate waiting time between first attempt "$last_visit" and possible next attempt can be after 30 min of first one.

Not sure but code return current time is greater than future time...

```
<?php 

  function pa($arr) {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($arr);  
        echo '< /pre>';  
   }

   $lastv="2014-03-31 02:30:00";
   $counter['last']= $lastv."  ".strtotime($lastv);
   $counter['next']= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', ((strtotime($lastv))+ (30 * 60)))."  ".((strtotime($lastv))+ (50 * 60));            
   $counter['current']= date('Y-m-d h:i:s', time())."  ".time();
   $counter['wait']=((strtotime($lastv))+ (30 * 60))-time();

    pa($counter);

?>
```

results

```
Array
(
    [last] => 2014-03-31 02:30:00  1396233000
    [next] => 2014-03-31 03:00:00  1396236000
    [current] => 2014-03-31 02:57:51  1396277871
    [wait] => -43071
)
```

code@runnable : http://runnable.com/UzmAZPw7_WxrNqsy/php-time

Comment: sorry,can you briefly explain what do you want?

Comment: I want to enable user to do an action only after 30min of last attempt. problem is that i get current time greater than next attempt time (which is after current time).

Comment: question may be better asked as: next attempt can be after **at least 30 minutes** of the first one. i.e. 30 minutes or more.

Comment: The biggest issue is where do you store the 'failing event' time. You cannot store it in a session as they go away after 30 minutes. You cannot store it in a cookie as the client can delete them. The only place is on a database or file. And you need to link it to an ip address and not a user id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which time zone you are in but it is working fine for me. What might be confusing you is that you show the time in "current" with `h` instead of `H` therefore at this time of day (afternoon in Europe) it shows 5 instead of 17.

If I correct this, the result makes sense:

```
Array
(
    [last] => 2014-03-31 02:00:00  1396231200
    [next] => 2014-03-31 03:00:00  1396234200
    [current] => 2014-03-31 15:43:47  1396280627
    [wait] => -45827
)
```

3 o'clock in the morning was about 12 hours ago, i.e. a little under 10 hours = -45827

Answer (score 0):

Here is a test function that accepts DateTime objects and calculate the **number of seconds to wait**. It return Zero if you have exceeded the wait time.

I have changed it to accept strings as input. I have allowed the 'current time' to be passed so that you can unit test it but it is optional, as is the delay.

Change the 'Right now' values to see it working now.

Tested code: PHP 5.3.18.

```
<?php // 22765002/php-current-time-greater-than-time


   // Testing -- set this to test the code...
   $currentTime    = "2014-03-31 04:25:00"; // current time for testing!

   // Testing -- set this to when the user messed up
   $failedAttempt  = "2014-03-31 03:00:00";

   // show stuff
   $fa = new DateTime($failedAttempt); // as DateTime
   $ct = new DateTime($currentTime);   // as DateTime

   // stuff to show
   $counter['whenFailed']       = $fa->format('d/m/Y H:i');
   $counter['current']          = $ct->format('d/m/Y H:i');
   $counter['wait']  = secondsToWait($failedAttempt, $currentTime); // call the function

   pa($counter); // display


   // -----------------
   // show right now!!!
   // -----------------

   echo 'Right now <br />';
   echo 'Seconds to wait is: ', secondsToWait("2014-03-31 18:50:00"), '<br />';
   echo 'Right now <br />';
  exit;

  /**
   * @param DateTime / string
   *                   Date and Time of the Failed Attempt
   *                   if string then must be sensible :-/
   *
   *  @param DateTime / string -- optional
   *                   The Current Time -- default is now()
   *                   if string then must be sensible :-/
   *
   * @param  Integer    Number of seconds to wait -- default 1800

   * This will:
   *    be positive for times less than 30 minutes from the start
   *    be zero     at 30 minites from the start
   *
   *    We want to know how long we have to 'wait' before trying again...
   *
   *    We want to show the 'wait' as positive or ZERO!
   *    where zero means they can try again...
   *
   * @return integer       number of seconds to wait before next attempt
   */
  function secondsToWait($whenFailed, $currentTime = null, $delaySeconds = 1800)
  {
      if (is_string($whenFailed)) {
          $whenFailed = new DateTime($whenFailed);
      }


      if (is_null($currentTime)) {
         $currentTime = new DateTime();
      }
      else if (is_string($currentTime)) {
          $currentTime = new DateTime($currentTime);
      }


      $whenNextAllowed  = new DateTime();
      $whenNextAllowed->setTimestamp($whenFailed->getTimestamp() + $delaySeconds);

      $waitSeconds = $whenNextAllowed->getTimestamp() - $currentTime->getTimestamp();

      if ($waitSeconds < 0) {
          $waitSeconds = 0;
      }
      return $waitSeconds;
  }
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------

  // display
  function pa($arr)
  {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($arr);
        echo '< /pre>';
   }
```